# fitting over a function with a for loop

Tags: python, curve-fitting, function-fitting

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I want fit over the following function with curve_fit:

```
def fct(A, Ravg,sigma,pos,omega, x):
    K=integrate.quad(lambda R:np.exp( - (R-Ravg)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),Ravg-sigma,Ravg+sigma)
    data=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        data.append(integrate.quad(lambda R: (3*(np.sin(x[i]*R)-x[i]*R*np.cos(x[i]*R))/(x[i]*R)**3)**2*1/K[0] *np.exp( - (R-Ravg)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),Ravg-sigma,Ravg+sigma))
    gafs=array(data)
    return A*gafs[:,0]
```

I get from curve_fit with this code:

```
fitPars, covMatrix = curve_fit(fct, xaxis, yaxis)
```

The following error message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

I understand that the error comes from the for loop. Do you have an idea how can I make my function suitable for curvefit?

The full error track is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3e25e14bdca2> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 fitPars, covMatrix = curve_fit(fct, xaxis, yaxis)

C:\Programfiles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    734         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    735         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 736         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    737         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    738         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

C:\Programfiles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    375     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    376         args = (args,)
--> 377     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    378     m = shape[0]
    379     if n > m:

C:\Programfiles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

C:\Programfiles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    452     if transform is None:
    453         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 454             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    455     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    456         def func_wrapped(params):

<ipython-input-3-4ae12bf8a77b> in fct(A, Ravg, sigma, pos, omega, x)
     52     K=integrate.quad(lambda R:np.exp( - (R-Ravg)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),Ravg-sigma,Ravg+sigma)
     53     data=[]
---> 54     for i in range(0,len(x)):
     55         data.append(integrate.quad(lambda R: (3*(np.sin(x[i]*R)-x[i]*R*np.cos(x[i]*R))/(x[i]*R)**3)**2*1/K[0] *np.exp( - (R-Ravg)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),Ravg-sigma,Ravg+sigma))
     56     gafs=array(data)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Comment: Can you please include the whole error trace? Otherwise it is hard to track, from where exactly the error originates.

Comment: The error does not come from within the loop but from the `range(0,len(x)` expression in the loop specification. What do you expect `len(x)` to be? All but the first parameter passed to `fct` are simple numbers and no arrays..

Comment: my guess is that `def fct(A, Ravg,sigma,pos,omega, x)` should have `x` as its first argument.

Comment: len(x) is the length of my data set. The other parameters are simple numbers.

Comment: It seems like you're passing to `fct` a parameter `x` that's a float (and not a list/array)

Comment: ...yep... `curve_fit` needs the function to take the independent as first argument, then parameters

Comment: The Problem is solved. The x have to be the first argument. Thanks a lot.